# Delta-epsilon proof for the integer part ( $[x]$ ) function.

Tags: calculus, limits

I was doing some of my exercises and started to think how could I prove, for example:
$\lim\limits_{ x\rightarrow3}[x]$. I know this limit doesn't exist, however, proofs for the lateral limits should be constructable, and I have no idea how.

Comment: Can you show that $\lim\limits_{ x\rightarrow 3^-}[x]=2$ and $\lim\limits_{ x\rightarrow 3^+}[x]=3$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for the existence of the left-hand and right-hand limits

To get the left hand limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow3^-}[x]=2$ we need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<3-a<\delta$ then $|2-[a]|<\epsilon$.

However, this is easy to prove: All we have to do is choose $\delta=1$ for every $\epsilon$ since whenever $0<3-a<1$, we have $2<a<3$, so $[a]=2$ and so $|2-[a]|=0<\epsilon$.

The statement for the right hand limit $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow3^+}[x]=3$ is worked out in exactly the same manner: we need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<a-3<\delta$ then $|[a]-3|<\epsilon$.

Again it suffices to choose $\delta=1$ for every $\epsilon$ because we have $0<a-3<1$ implies $3<a<4$ which implies $[a]=3$ which gives us $|[a]-3|=0<\epsilon$.

Note that since we have shown the left-hand and right-hand limits are different, we have also proven that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow3}[x]$ does not exist.